# Pandas Dataframe replace values in a Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to update my_df based on conditional selection as in:

```
my_df[my_df['group'] == 'A']['rank'].fillna('A+')
```

However, this is not persistence ... e.g: the my_df still have NaN or NaT  ... and I am not sure how to do this in_place.   Please advise on how to persist the the update to my_df.

Comment: From the answers below, you have two problems.  First, is that you are not re-assign your results back to the dataframe.  And, two you have index chaining going on.  Index chaining in this situation can be avoid by using `loc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean mask and assign to filtered column `rank`:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('AAAABC'),
                     'rank':['a','b',np.nan, np.nan, 'c',np.nan],
                     'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})

print (my_df)
  group rank  C
0     A    a  7
1     A    b  8
2     A  NaN  9
3     A  NaN  4
4     B    c  2
5     C  NaN  3

m = my_df['group'] == 'A'
my_df.loc[m, 'rank'] = my_df.loc[m, 'rank'].fillna('A+')

print(my_df)
  group rank  C
0     A    a  7
1     A    b  8
2     A   A+  9
3     A   A+  4
4     B    c  2
5     C  NaN  3
```

Comment: Hi @jscriptor, I recommend accept this answer , since the clean code is equally important with logic . (Always using mask for the condition is good for future modify )

Comment: Thanks a lot.   All answers worked but this breaking up into 2 ops help me see  what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign it back

```
my_df.loc[my_df['group'] == 'A','rank']=my_df.loc[my_df['group'] == 'A','rank'].fillna('A+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your operations are not in-place, so you need to assign back to a variable. In addition, chained indexing is not recommended.

One option is [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with a Boolean series:

```
# data from @jezrael

df['rank'].mask((df['group'] == 'A') & df['rank'].isnull(), 'A+', inplace=True)

print(df)

   C group rank
0  7     A    a
1  8     A    b
2  9     A   A+
3  4     A   A+
4  2     B    c
5  3     C  NaN
```